# read from .bash_profile via python

Tags: python, bash

is there any way to read the .bash_profile using python?
I need to get value of one of variables, like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java
```

Comment: `os.environ['JAVA_HOME']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the value of a particular environment variable, there is no need to parse .bash_profile.  Just check in `os.environ`.

```
import os
os.environ['JAVA_HOME']
```